# CSS file has contents locally but in browser is empty

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

I created a website (on local host for now), so I linked html with css and my css is ready.  I wrote everything, but then the css doesnt show on the website

I opened the `inspect element > sources > style.css` and I found the css empty, but in vs code it has 1200 lines in Chrome its 0 (I saved the folder after writing the css)

Here is the template code that I used to link with css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache. Also see [ask]. Your question needs more detail.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the directory structure as well as the part of the HTML where you link your CSS. Maybe also have a look at the Browser's console and look at error messages that might get printed there and provide those if any.

Comment: okay wait @Mushroomator

Comment: done I did it @Mushroomator

Comment: What language/framework is `{% static 'css/style.css' %}`?

Comment: Looks like you are using a template engine? Which one are you using and how is it configured. Also as @isherwood suggest might wanna try to clear your browser cache or reload the page ignoring the cache by pressing `Ctrl` + `F5`. And you are still missing the directory structure. We cannot verify that the path used is correct otherwise. Might wanna use `tree` to provide that.

Comment: yes its django @rguttersohn

Comment: You should definitely add the Django tag to your question.

Comment: I tried to clear the cache, it didn't work

Comment: okay @rguttersohn I did

Comment: If clearing cache did not help then this is probably not the file you think.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the server port works for me.
First I run this command: py manage.py runserver 3000
And when I tried again: py manage.py runserver ->it starts to work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the Server Port.
For example:

```
py manage.py runserver 3000
```

Comment: doesnt work... any other recommendation ?